# ng build --prod doesn't generate dist folder

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

`ng build --prod` doesn't generate dist folder. I run it in root folder of the project. No errors in the console, all good, but no dist folder. What's going on?

```
   chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.44 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} main.8cc815547c2028732f44.js (main) 324 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.1830021e03d1c0db3030.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} styles.c749130dfed64f175ac0.css (styles) 55 bytes [initial] [rendered]
```

Comment: if no errors occured in console, that makes no sense for me, if it is possible, is there an online repo for it ?

Comment: try reloading ide!

Comment: That's an interesting one, can you do a search for those file names and come up with nothing?

Comment: Check your `angular.json` make sure there's `outputPath`. Also check `tsconfig` make sure you do not have `dist` path excluded.

Comment: Open `tsconfig.json` and check `compilerOptions.outDir` ?

Comment: Reloading ide, helped, I just didn't see it in the ide, it was there all the time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reloading IDE! Sometimes the newly generated folders do not get indexed right away. You can make sure if the folder is created or not by actually going to the project folder location through explorer not through IDE.